# Problems uploading image file with multer (React and Node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I've spent hours trying to find the solution for something which should be quite simple: uploading a file to the server from the client. I am using React.js on the frontend, Express on the backend, and `multer` for the image uploads.

When I try to upload a file, nothing happens. An `uploads/` directory is created, but no file goes there. `req.file` and `req.files` are `undefined`. `req.body.file` is empty. The form data exists before it is sent.

If I set the `Content-Type` header to `"multipart/form-data"` I get a boundary error from `multer`.

**Input**

```
<input 
    onChange={this.sendFile}
    name="avatar"
    placeholder="Choose avatar"
    type="file"
/>
```

**sendFile**

```
sendFile = e => {
    const data = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    data.append("file", file);
    this.props.sendFile(data);
};
```

**Redux action**

```
export default file => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/upload/", { file });
};
```

**Express**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

router.post("/upload/", upload.single("avatar"), (req, res) => {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it and made it work with this method:

```
sendFile = e => {
  const data = new FormData();
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  data.append("avatar", file); // <-- use "avatar" instead of "file" here
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/upload',
    data: data,
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
  });
};
```

Comment: Great! It worked for me. Even for a array consisting of images, it got uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the content-type header to `multipart/form-data` in the axios request and send the full FormData object as the second parameter.

Like this:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
};
axios.post('/api/upload/', file, headers);`
```